# Importing a CSV file which contains French Characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a CSV file which has French Characters in some of the fields.
But when I import this data into a DB. I do not see French characters instead it shows some other special characters.

Query I am using to import the `.csv` file is as follows:

```
--Create Table 
Create Table A_test (A_1 VARCHAR(100))

--Bulk Import .csv file with ANSI encoding
BULK INSERT A_Test  
   FROM 'C:\A_Test.csv'  
   WITH   
      (  DataFileType = 'widechar',
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
      ); 

--Sample Data in C:\A_Test.csv file
Le vieux château
Une fête
Le dîner
L'hôtel
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please provide a small file sample ( a few lines) and a table definition.

Comment: Sample Data:

Le vieux château
Une fête
Le dîner
L'hôtel

Comment: @Alex - Heh. Sorry, might have jumped the gun there. I assumed he was trying to direct us to a file with sample data somewhere. I removed the comment. However, without the table/column definitions, we still can't assist. I'm guessing the issue is that the collation of the table is wrong, or it's been defined as varchar instead of nvarchar.

Comment: @SchmitzIT I tried changing collation of the DB too.. But no use still the same error..
Even I changed column to NVARCHAR(100) but after import from .csv file still I don't see any french chars in table..

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the collation of the affected columns by running the following code (I just made up the column name and datatype):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.a_test
ALTER COLUMN somecolumn varchar(100) COLLATE French_CI_AS NOT NULL;
```

Also you could create the original table with the relevant columns pre-collated:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.a_test
(
[somecolumn] varchar(100) COLLATE French_CI_AS NOT NULL
)
```

BULK INSERT like this:

```
BULK INSERT a_test from 'C:\etc.txt' WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar')
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, at least for me. I suspect the issue is with the initial file encoding and pre 2016 version SQL Server's luck of UTF-8 support.

Comment: OK I understand, if you keep the a_test table in the French collation, open up the file you are importing from and save it as a Unicode text document (just at the bottom of the 'save as' dialogue box is an option for encoding, choose Unicode). Then BULK INSERT from the Unicode file into a_test making sure that the BULK INSERT looks like (see edited answer).

Comment: Incidentally, if the columns concerned are the varchar datatype, I would suggest using nvarchar.

Comment: In my testing the key to success is the Unicode file. Type of column did not make any difference.

Comment: Indeed, however look at these two pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql

and 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql

In which Microsoft themselves define varchar and nvarchar as 'non-unicode' and 'unicode' string data respectively.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply..
I tried by saving the file with unicode text document. It is working fine.
But It's kind of I am modifying the file which client dont want.

Comment: I have updated the question.. with all the Query.. could anyone suggest me any other workaround for the same???

Comment: @russ Even I tried by changing DB collation to French_CI_AS.. But still the same error

Comment: The original file that the client sent you, is the file a text document? If so, when you open it and click on 'Save As', what encoding does it show? If ANSI or UTF-8 then you're going to have to demand that the client is OK for you to modify it.

Comment: @russ Its in ANSI encoding format..
Is there any alternate way of doing this through SQL server ?
File contain 200000+ records if I save it with some other encoding I hope its wont change data inside the file..??

Comment: Saving it in Unicode more-or-less definitely won't change anything, but you could perform the following check for peace of mind: (1) Import the data into SQL Server from a Unicode file. (2) (a) Import the data from the Unicode file into Excel (Data tab - From Text) or (b) copy and paste the data from the Unicode file into Excel. (3) Goto SQL Server and Select * the data. (4) (a) Literally copy and paste the data from the results window, into Excel. Or (b) you might know how to Export it from SQL Server to Excel... (opendatasource or openrowset methinks).

Comment: (5) Compare the two datasets using the EXACT function in Excel to make sure that they are exactly the same, and to show that saving it in Unicode didn't change anything!